# How to use _popen() with string input?

Tags: c, windows, popen

I try to use `_popen()` to view files. When I write one word command like `ipconfig` or `dir` it works fine. However when I try something with space in it like `cd ..` or `cd C:\`, it won't work(it won't change the directory), the program just does nothing. I don't get a error. I'm on a Windows machine. I don't know if it has anything to do with the spaces. I tried something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        char buff[500];
        char input[100];
    
        printf("Command: ");
        fgets(input, 100, stdin);
    
        FILE* f = _popen(input, "r");
    
        while (fgets(buff, 200, f) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", buff);
        }
    
        _pclose(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Generally, we very much value questions that include **complete** examples, i.e. code that can be copied, pasted, and compiled to reproduce exactly what you are seeing; your example is missing the `#include` statements and an `int main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because cd does not produce any output. In other words, does not write to stdout

Try "dir c:" and see if you can read from the pipe

```
Command: cd ..
Command: dir c:
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F4DC-394E

 Directory of popen

15-03-2022  15:28    <DIR>          .
15-03-2022  15:28    <DIR>          ..
15-03-2022  15:28    <DIR>          Debug
15-03-2022  15:28               520 popen.cpp
```

Comment: Sidenote: If you (@KinoDerToten) expected your program to change the directory *permanently*, i.e. leaving you in a different directory than the one you started the executable from, note that running the executable creates *a new process*, and that `cd` would affect that process only, not the *calling* process. I.e., the `cd` *does* happen, but only for (and until the end of) the process executing your programm. The *calling* process remains in its current directory.